# On partial sum of reciprocal primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

Is it true that

$$\sum_{p \le p_k} \frac{1}{p} - \ln\ln p_k - B > 0$$

holds for all sufficiently large $k$?

(Being $p_k$ the k-th prime number and B a constant defined by $B = \gamma + \sum_{p} \ln{(1-\frac{1}{p})} + \frac {1}{p} $ whose value is 0.26149 aprox.)

Thank you.

**Added:** if that were true, why does the third answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/102724/100873) use its absolute value? Would it make any difference?

Comment: @Burde I had already regarded that article but I did not find the answer to if $$\sum_{p \le p_k} \frac{1}{p} - \ln\ln p_k - B$$ is always greater than 0

Comment: I would like to prove it mathematically as I want to know, if it holds, the smallest value for k for it to be true. I have tried it for some random numbers with no counterexample found

Comment: The picture [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel–Mertens_constant) suggests that it is true.

Comment: @Burde Thank you, that helps a lot, but I would rather prefer a mathematical proof